# Sql add price and date difference to columns

Tags: sql, price, date-difference

I have a mini project on a hotel and Im trying to add two more columns to my table in sql database that shows how many days someone stayed so a date difference and the price of staying for x amount of days. Also I’m very new

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that this site is not a free coding site. Individuals here are more than willing to help you but you must provide examples of what you have tried already, actual result, and expected result. Please visit this page for more information on how to best ask your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Specifically, it might help to use something like https://dbfiddle.uk/ to present a representative data set and table structure, plus you can also specify your DBMS.  All of this will make it easier for people to give you answers.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e2aa/4